# lightning-input: what is the purpose of message-when-too-long?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

The `lightning-input` component has a documented property, `message-when-too-long`, which is described as: "Error message to be displayed when the value is too long." in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification).  Presumably, this is based on the value of the `max-length` property.

In practice, the `lightning-input` element appears to prevent the user from entering any characters beyond the number specified in `max-length`, even when copying and pasting.  So it would appear `message-when-too-long` does not have any real purpose.  The component will never allow you to encounter that message.

Am I missing something here?

#### 8/22/2022 update

Note that when you set the value of the `lightning-input` programmatically, the `message-when-too-long` value still does not appear. For example, with a component like this...

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input
        type="text"
        label="Name"
        value={name}
        max-length="3"
        message-when-too-long="too dang long"
        onchange={handleNameChange}
    ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class LwcApp extends LightningElement {
    name;
    handleNameChange(event) {
        this.name = "a name that is too long";
        event.target.reportValidity();
    }
}
```

...you get this, without a red validation message:

[image: no validation message]

Comment: What if the current value is programmatically set to a value that is too long?

Comment: See updated question -- I don't believe `lightning-input` re-evaluates its validity when programmatic updates are made to the value. I did notice that by programmatically setting a value that is too long, then deleting a character from the input manually, I was able to trigger the message as long as the resulting value was still too long. So I guess that could be a use case? But I don't think this is what developers are envisioning when they implement `message-when-too-long`.

Comment: What you reported above was what I was expecting - that editing a too long values that remains too long can show this message.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly that: '**Error message to be displayed when the value is too long.**'
Check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification)

Id you have a field that have set a maximum number of characters you can add this attribute `message-when-too-long` to your tag to inform the user of that issue for that particular field.

Comment: Seems to be missing the point.  See playground example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/-9qNLhyK/1/edit

Comment: I think if you set the limit on the input field message-when-too-long is not going to work. Perhaps you need to add a SObject field and set the limit on the field level. After that, add that field to your HTML and try to go over the limit that was set on the field created in the SObject on the Fields and Relationships.