# What is the use of messageWhenTooLong function in lightning input or textarea

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput, lightning-textarea

What is the use of messageWhenTooLong function in lightning input or textarea.
In practice, the lightning-input element appears to prevent the user from entering any characters beyond the number specified in max-length, even when copying and pasting. So it would appear message-when-too-long does not have any real purpose. The component will never allow you to encounter that message.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: duplicate question, but the answer here is a detailed one.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292202/lightning-input-what-is-the-purpose-of-message-when-too-long

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific section for it in [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) that calls out its lack of use and how to implement something like this with other options:

> maxlength limits the number of characters you can enter. **The
> messageWhenTooLong error message isn't triggered because you can't
> type more than the number of characters allowed. However, you can use
> the messageWhenPatternMismatch and pattern attributes to trigger a
> message on blur when too many characters are entered.**

So if you did want to provide some sort of message based on number of characters, you'd want to leverage `pattern` and `messageWhenPatternMismatch`

```html
<lightning:input 
    type="text" 
    messageWhenPatternMismatch="Too many characters!" 
    pattern=".{0,5}" 
    name="input-name" 
    label="Enter up to 5 characters" 
/>
```

Why have `message-when-too-long` if it doesn't seem to have a purpose?

I think the simplest answer is that it used to be needed or there's older browsers/technologies (ex. IE11) where you could possibly paste more characters than the `maxLength`. I noticed, in a quick test, that mobile seemed to allow more than max characters while inputting values (though no error showed) and then truncated on the focus away.